# Why does this boolean computation get stuck?

Tags: function-construction, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I want to build a boolean function which takes three one-parametric functions. I really don't know how to write a function for this, but this seems to be working for me as long as the parameter is `t`.

```
isCorrect[f1_, f2_, f3_] := Assuming[t >= 0, Refine[If[
                             1 + f1 + f2 + f3 >= 0 && 
                             1 + f1 - f2 - f3 >= 0 && 
                             1 - f1 + f2 - f3 >= 0 && 
                             1 - f1 - f2 + f3 >= 0, True, False]]]
```

For some functions it gives the correct value.

```
In[]:= isCorrect[Cos[t], Cos[t], 1]
Out[]= True
```

But for some examples like below it does not output anything.

```
In[]:= isCorrect[Exp[-t] Cos[t], Exp[-t], Exp[-t]]
Out[]= If[1 - 2 E^-t + E^-t Cos[t] >= 0, True, False]
```

But I know that `Plot[1 - 2 E^-t + E^-t Cos[t], {t,0,10}]` returns the following and is always non-negative for positive t.

[image]

So I don't know why `isCorrect` does not output `True` then.

Any hints would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

```
In[]:= Assuming[t >= 0, Reduce[1 - 2 E^-t + E^-t Cos[t] >= 0]]` 
Out[]:= Cos[t] \[Element] Reals && ((E^-t < 0 && Cos[t] <= E^t (-1 + 2 E^-t)) || E^-t == 0 || (E^-t > 0 && Cos[t] >= E^t (-1 + 2 E^-t)))
```

Why can't it figure out `E^-t` can't be negative ever. Also, `Cos[t]` is always real since `t` is explicitly assumed to be positive.

Comment: I think Refine simply could not decide on the value of the expression. `Reduce[1 - 2 E^-t + E^-t Cos[t] >= 0, t]` can't also decide. So `Refine` returned the expression back. Help on `Refine` says `gives the form of expr that would be obtained if symbols in it were replaced by explicit numerical expressions satisfying the assumptions assum`

Comment: @Nasser So is there no function which would decide the value?

Comment: I do not know. But for this one specific case, if you add one more conditions, then it can do it. `Refine[If[1 - 2 E^-t + E^-t Cos[t] >= 0, True, False], 
 t >= 0 && 1 >= 2 E^-t - E^-t Cos[t]]` gives `True`. So I think your conditions you put there are not complete or may be need more refinement. I do not know why Reduce also can't do it.

Comment: @Nasser, that is weird, isn't it? I should probably evaluate numerically and check it.

Comment: `Assuming[t >= 0, Reduce[1 - 2 E^-t + E^-t Cos[t] >= 0]]` results in
`Cos[t] \[Element] 
  Reals && ((E^-t < 0 && Cos[t] <= E^t (-1 + 2 E^-t)) || 
   E^-t == 0 || (E^-t > 0 && Cos[t] >= E^t (-1 + 2 E^-t)))`. Very weird to see that, cos is a real function and `E^-t` can never be negative.

Comment: Something is going on that I do not understand. Hopefully someone will figure it out.

Comment: Note that `Assuming[]` will **not** affect `Reduce[]`, because `Reduce[]` does not have the `Assumptions` option.

Comment: `In[27]:= Resolve[
 ForAll[t, 0 <= t < 40 Pi, 1 - 2 E^-t + E^-t Cos[t] >= 0]]

Out[27]= True` But if I replace `40Pi` with `Infinity` then it returns unevaluated. Go figger.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The [`If`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html) construct is unnecessary, and an optional variable designation can be included.

```
isCorrect[f1_, f2_, f3_, var : _Symbol : t] := Assuming[var >= 0,
  Refine[1 + f1 + f2 + f3 >= 0 && 1 + f1 - f2 - f3 >= 0 && 
    1 - f1 + f2 - f3 >= 0 && 1 - f1 - f2 + f3 >= 0]]

isCorrect[Cos[t], Cos[t], 1]

(* True *)
```

Using a different variable,

```
isCorrect[Cos[x], Cos[x], 1, x]

(* True *)
```

For the second example,

```
ex = isCorrect[Exp[-t] Cos[t], Exp[-t], Exp[-t]]

(* 1 - 2 E^-t + E^-t Cos[t] >= 0 *)
```

While neither [`Refine`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refine.html) or [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) resolves this expression, for this inequality you can use [`MinValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinValue.html) ([`Minimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize.html)).

```
MinValue[{ex[[1]], t >= 0}, t] >= 0

(* True *)
```

Equivalently,

```
ex2 = ex // Simplify[#, t >= 0] &

(* E^t + Cos[t] >= 2 *)

MinValue[{ex2[[1]], t >= 0}, t] >= 2

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks. I rewrote the function `isCorrect[f1_, f2_, f3_, var : _Symbol : t] :=
 MinValue[{1 + f1 + f2 + f3, var >= 0}, var] >= 0 && MinValue[{1 + f1 - f2 - f3, var >= 0}, var] >= 0 && MinValue[{1 - f1 + f2 - f3, var >= 0}, var] >= 0 && MinValue[{1 - f1 - f2 + f3, var >= 0}, var] >= 0`, (I don't know how to use MapThread for this). But, `isCorrect[Exp[-t] Cos[t], Exp[-t], Exp[-t]]` still does not resolve. Evaluating individually gives the correct answer.

Comment: As you noted, `If` is not needed. Since  `>=` will already return a Boolean value.